# How to update a separated element with axios?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, symfony, axios

My code right now works perfectly fine!
It updates the user status(disable, enable account)  without refreshing the page.
Right now if I click to the red button `Desactiver` it will become green `Activer` and the same thing in reverse..

What I wanna do is: When I Click to the button the status also get updated (which is in a **different** `<td>` )

In my axios code, I tried to get the status element using

```
const statusText= this.querySelector('span.status11');
```

and update it using

```
statusText.textContent=response.data.current;
```

The problem is that using **this.querySelector**  return null because it is in a different `<td>`
and **this** points to `a.js-status` because on my code i did

```
 document.querySelectorAll('a.js-status').forEach(function(link)
```

Here is the image
[image]

Here is my current code that updates ONLY the button (while i wanna update the button + the status `<td>`

Controller function:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{id}/status", name="user_status", methods={"GET","POST"})
 * @param Request $request
 * @param User $user
 * @return Response
 */
public function updateStatus(User $user): Response
{
    if($user->getStatus()==true){
        $user->setStatus(false);
        $current="Desactiver";
    } else {
        $user->setStatus(true);
        $current="Activer";
    } 
    $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
        return $this->json([
            'code'=>200,
            'message'=>'the Status of is updated',
            'current'=>$current
        ],200);
    }
```

html code :

```
{% if user.status == 0 %}
      Compte est <span class="status11" >Desactiver</span> 
{% else %}
      Compte est <span class="status11" >Activer</span> 
{% endif %}
    </td>

    <td>
{% if user.status == 1 %}
       <a href="{{ path('user_status', {'id': user.id}) }}" class="js-status"> <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Desactiver</button></a>
{% else %}
       <a href="{{ path('user_status', {'id': user.id}) }}" class="js-status"> <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Activer</button></a>
{% endif %}
    </td>
```

My axios/javascript code :

```
{% block javascripts %}
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"> </script>
    <script>

        function onClickBtnLike(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            const url = this.href;
            const btn= this.querySelector('button');

            axios.get(url).then(function(response){
                
               if(btn.classList.contains('btn-danger')) {
                    btn.classList.replace('btn-danger','btn-success');
                    btn.textContent="Activer";
               }else{
                    btn.classList.replace('btn-success','btn-danger'); 
                    btn.textContent="Desactiver";
                }
            });
        }

        document.querySelectorAll('a.js-status').forEach(function(link){
            link.addEventListener('click',onClickBtnLike);
        })
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [traverse up](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) from the button to the containing row and search for your status `span` from there:

```
const status = this.closest('tr').querySelector('.status11');

status.textContent = (status.textContent == "Activer" ? "Desactiver" : "Activer");
```

You could also target the previous `td` directly by using `this.parentElement.previousElementSibling` but the former is clearer and gives you some leeway if you want to change the html structure.